# Can I manipulate/manage some website through Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-app

I need to simulate the user's work - click buttons, enter data in the field and so on. Is this can be done only through  using executeScript or I can receive DOM of  and manipulate with it? Or maybe I can work with the tab in the browser separately or exist some other way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you can do this with a Chrome App, but you can do this using a Chrome Extension.  Extensions can have full access to a tab's DOM and you can manipulate the DOM as needed. (e.g. fill in form fields, click buttons, etc...).

From: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

> Extensions can interact with web pages or servers using content scripts or cross-origin XMLHttpRequests.

This is how extensions like LastPass are able to fill in the username and password field on any web page you visit.